# Symfony2: form field gets "required"even if is not set as it in form or Twig template

Tags: php, symfony, caching, nginx

I am defining a field on my Form class as follow:

```
->add('alternative_email', 'email', array(
    'trim' => true,
    'required' => false
))
```

And also have tried on this way:

```
->add('alternative_email', 'text', array(
    'trim' => true,
    'required' => false
))
```

Then on the template where I'm rendering that field I just do this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.user.alternative_email, {'attr':{'class':'form-control'}})}}
```

Any time I render that form I get this as output:

```
<input type="email" id="natural_user_alternative_email" name="natural[user][alternative_email]" required="required" class="form-control" data-bv-field="natural[user][alternative_email]">
```

Why the `required` attributed is being added?

As a sidenote I'm using [BootstrapValidator](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/) by setting this validation rules on that field:

```
'natural[user][alternative_email]': {
    validators: {
        emailAddress: {},
        different: {
            field: 'natural[user][email]',
        }
    }
}
```

Which means:

- A valid email address
- Current email (alternative_email) different from the one on `natural[user][email]`

Furthermore I have clear the cache several times by deleting all the content of `app/cache` by hand (`rm -rf app/ cache`) I have clear APC cache by running `php -r "apc_clear_cache(); apc_clear_cache('user'); apc_clear_cache('opcode');"` and finally restarted both services: `php-fpm` and `nginx`.

I'm also working in a Chrome "incognito window" so contents won't be cached. Can any give me some help on this weird issue?

**Running some other test: how could this be possible??**

Trying to find where the issue comes from I ran some other test and surprise I am confused at this point since this can't be possible. See I've changed the field definition on the form class as:

```
->add('email_alternative', 'text', array(
    'trim' => true,
    'required' => false
))
```

And didn't touch any other part of my code so template remains intact and ask for render `alternative_email` field. As expected that should goes through a error right? Well NOT, no errors, page still render and field keep calling `natural[user][alternative_email]`, how could this be possible?

I've stopped Nginx and started Apache to test if some kind of weird cache already exists but the same as before happen: no errors, field keep call `natural[user][alternative_email]`, any clue?

**NOTE**: I'm using Symfony 2.6.1

Comment: correo_alternativo or alternative_email?

Comment: @Cerad `alternative_email` just a typo during translation from Spanish to English sorry

Comment: Check that your controller call the right form type. Is the `required` attribute still there if you remove the  BootstrapValidator?

Comment: Yes, already tried that too, the last weird thing is that I remove complete a use statement and things keep going working so something really weird is happening here an I am not able to find what is, any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found where the problem was and I should said as almost always is a developer (me on this case) mistake and not framework itself. The problem was simple and A.L have right: controller was calling a similar form and I made changes in other. So all is fine now. Thanks to A.L for the tip